# Can't get my array in a function to update with new values once it reads the file

Tags: c, arrays, function

I have a function, with an array initialized outside of said function. Inside the function, I have set all values of my array to zero, so that it doesn't return some garbage. I'm trying to scan the file, and using the numbers it scans in the file (for instance, 7), update the index of the array by adding one (index 7's value is now 1). The while loop will crash the program, first off, and when I use a for loop the program runs, but the values won't update. I need to have my loop run for an unknown amount of time, but I suppose that's a matter for another time.

```
void createVArray (FILE*votes, int ray[], int len){

    votes=fopen("votes.txt","r");

    int i,k,num;

    for(i=1;i<len;i++){
        ray[i]=0;
    }

    while(num!=30){
    fscanf(votes,"%d",&num);
        ray[num]++;
    }

}
```

Any idea on what the issue is?

Comment: Why do you pass `votes` as argument?

Comment: In the parameters? The instructions for the program say "This is a void function that takes three parameters: a FILE * and an integer
array and an integer indicating the length of the array." If that's not what you are referring to, can you explain what you mean? I've only been coding for a few weeks. @juanchopanza

Comment: @ctelchi He surely does refer to that . You can simply declare file pointer inside function body.

Comment: @ameyCU So it's not necessary to put the actual file in the parameter list? I can declare and open within the function? EDIT: Tried to take it out of the parameter list and put it in the body of the function but then it said that it wasn't declared in the scope.

Comment: @ctelchi It just seems odd, because it is a local variable, and you don't modify the thing it points to. So there is no reason to pass it.

Comment: @ctelchi I see you don't set all the elements of the array to 0. In C/C++, array indexing begins at 0.

Comment: @ctelchi To me it seems you should open the file outside of the function and pass the FILE pointer. Anyway, you have a bunch of bugs. Crank up the compiler's warning level to 11.

Comment: @juanchopanza I originally did have the file open up in main, but that made no difference.

Comment: Well, now you have a useless parameter. Think of how confusing that would be to someone using your function. They would have to pass a FILE pointer for nothing. And you would have to document that it will get ignored.

Comment: @ctelchi Other thing use `do-while` instead of `while` here.

Comment: @ameyCU I switched it, the program still crashes. Not sure what the issue is.

Comment: @Polb thanks for that, I fixed it. But I don't think it matters because I'm only operating on values 1-20, and printing 1-20 out.

Comment: @ctelchi You sure that `num` does not access index out of bounds . I mean are you sure that `len` and size of array is atleat `30`?

Comment: @ameyCU Why does the length of the array need to be thirty? The size of the array is 21, and I'm scanning a file with several values ranging from 1-20, with the intention of incrementing their respective index by one (counting votes, scanning a 7 counts one vote for index 7). The value 30 is where the program stops.

Comment: @ctelchi Thats what I am asking if any value come greater than `20` then an invalid index would be accessed and that would cause undefined behaviour .

Comment: @ameyCU I'm not sure who answered the question, its the top one that's not me, but I'm using that to ensure that an invalid index isn't accessed. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   while(num!=30){
    fscanf(votes,"%d",&num);
        ray[num]++;
    }
```

There are several things wrong here. First you don't initialize `num`, so the first time you compare `num` to `30` will cause undefined behavior. And where does the magic number `30` come from?

Second, after reading num you need to ensure that it is not greater than `(len-1)` before you increment `ray[num]`.

Perhaps something like this would work:

```
   while( fscanf(votes,"%d",&num) == 1 ) {
      if ( (num >= 0) && (num < len) ) {
        ray[num]++;
      }
   }
```

Comment: 30 comes from the file being read, which is where the program is supposed to stop reading. Is num not initialized in int?

Comment: `int num;` declares num as an int, but does not initialize it to anything.

Answer (score -1):

Alright guys. Problem solved. I'm just basically an idiot- I named my file "votes.txt" instead of just "votes" so it never even got to reading the file. Rock on. Thank you all for the help an pointers. Super appreciate the help.

Comment: _**When you get an answer which solves your problem don't post another answer instead accept that answer (by clicking small tick besides that answer)**_. Cheers :)

Comment: @ameyCU Ahh thank you. Done! First time using stackoverflow, does it show?